# Integrating Angular CLI with Squarespace

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli, squarespace

I am interested to know if anyone has been able to successfully use Angular CLI in a Squarespace site.

I have been searching for answers to this problem but can't find a solution. I know that you can add custom scripts to a Squarespace site and/or add scripts via CDN but Angular CLI apps are usually deployed using a different method.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

NOTE: I know that this is not a best practice and devs should deploy their Angular CLI app via AWS or with a similar platform.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one has answered this. Yes, there's no reason why you couldn't use AngularJS or any other Javascript library with Squarespace. You'll need a 'Business' level account, however, and you'll want to check out the developer portal here:

https://developers.squarespace.com

Squarespace provides you with a Git repository and a CLI that you can download via NPM that will let you run a local squarespace server and develop your site from scratch or with a base template.

You can check out their docs on 3rd party avascript (e.g. Angular) here:

https://developers.squarespace.com/custom-javascript/

Since your question is specifically about using the CLI, I would just note whatever your final 'production' bundle looks like and include that in your git repository, so that you can reference it in your main html page.